Can I completely omit "of" when speaking quickly?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_der_x5Zxmc
At 3:37 of this video the man says, as far as I'm concerned, "For portions of that first half we sort of dominated them".
I've slowed the audio down to be sure I'm hearing everything correctly.
I'm clearly hearing that in "portions of that" the sounds "s" and "th" are adjacent. But "s" and "th" can be adjacent in this phrase if and only if the word "of" is totally omitted.
Am I correct to say that "of" completely left out in this phrase? How dialectal and how common is it in Great Britain?

I can hear 'for portions uh the first 'alf'. The uh being barely audible. The speaker is under pressure to say a lot in a short time. That sort of shortening is OK in the circumstances.

The schwa itself (uh) is definitely present, and I expect a linguist with an oscilloscope could easily identify a minimal /v/ immediately after the schwa, even though it's not fully articulated in rapid speech like this. And as for the second "of" after "sort", the late John Lawler always wrote that as sorta - the final /v/ in sort of is often / usually dispensed with in casual speech.

"We actually look the better side." - COMPLETELY omits like and you're worried about of'teh?

No, you can't omit it. However, you can try and copy him. Footballers talk very fast. Try listening to others. He says uh instead of. This is common in what is called connected speech. This is not dialectal nor particularly British. Americans when talking fast also say uh instead a distinct of. For example: There were lots uh people at the party. SAID FAST.

The number of words per minute does not change the rules of grammar.

@JohnDouma No, of course not. DId anybody say it did?

@Lambie The question was exactly that.

@JohnDouma Speed of delivery and grammar have a complicated sound relationship in connected  speech.

@Mazura - there's nothing wrong with 'We actually look the better side'.

@JohnDouma - tell that to American tobacco and livestock auctioneers!

@FumbleFingers: I don't hear the schwa myself, so I don't think you can say it's definitely present. As for the /v/ you claim is there, it is definitely absent. You are rejecting the evidence of your own ears!

@TonyK: Professor of linguistics John Lawler often said that elements like that could be identified on an oscilloscope even though people might think they weren't articulated at all. And honestly, does it really matter if I hear what I'm expecting, rather than what the oscilloscope tells me? But in this specific case, I'm astonished that you would say you can't hear a schwa between ...for portions and that first 'alf. I certainly don't need a oscilloscope for that. Also note that native speakers would never deliberately discard that particular preposition in that context.

...but if I gave the impression there's a low-level /v/ there, that was a mistake. It's perfectly natural to discard the /v/ in such contexts (just not the neutral vowel itself). That's specifically what I meant about Lawler's sorta, which routinely discards trailing /v/

...but note that the final /s/ of portions is "voiced", so it may not be obvious that it's being slurred into another neutral vowel before the following consonant that.

In the  clip which the Original Poster has been watching, most of the speakers speak a Northern variety of British English.  In this type of English, the word of is often pronounced just as a vowel, usually a schwa, /ə/. This is what happens in the Original Poster's example. The faster the speaker is speaking the more likely this is to happen, although some speakers of Northern Englishes may use this vowel nearly all the time. There are lots of other very interesting  sounds and patterns in the speech in that clip. Beautiful.
The pronunciation of 'of' as a single vowel happens in other varieties of English too, but it doesn't happen often in Southern Standard British English.
The Original Speaker asks whether they should copy this type of speech. The answer is that if you live in the north of England, or somewhere else where they pronounce of like this, then it's up to you and how confident you feel doing it. Go for it! However, remember that not many people across the world are very familiar with English from the North of England. If you are going to be using your English in an international setting, you may want to use a more well-known variety of English as your main model.

The London working-class way of saying 'cup of tea' sounds like 'cuppa tea' to some, and the short for 'a cuppa' came into widespread use. However, despite international stereotypes, Britain's favourite hot drink is now coffee.

Sorta is common enough in American English that it’s in the dictionary now (but non-standard).

Americans say uh instead of a distinct of all the time. Plenty uh people know that. Northern dialect, indeed. I speak four languages and guess I never had a main model for any of them. I started Spanish with Argentinians, then moved to Caribbeans, then, Colombians and Venezuelans (not in a straight line either), and to top it off married a Spaniard.

@Lambie So you think the people in the clip are American?

"You are not really asking me that, are you?", she huffed indignantly. :) I said that any speaker of most varieties of English say uh for of in many cases in connected speech or when speaking fast, like that footballer.

@Davislor So 'sorta' is only sorta in the dictionary, then. And 'kinda' is kinda in the dictionary, for that matter

I just turned on CNN due to the missiles being lobbed at Israel (6:19 pm, EST) and am waiting for an uh for an of. Ha ha. But not haha overall, at all.

@Lambie In my American accent, I don’t reduce of to a vowel alla the time. It’s something I do when I’m speaking quickly and the syllable is unstressed. I also sometimes say “coulda,” “shoulda,” and “woulda.”

@Lambie Which is why some linguists say that words like could’ve are pronounced like could of and not like a contraction of could have.

@Davislor The ones you point out are other ones. Here, it was of to uh. Shall we spell out every single one or is it OK just to explain this one? I wasn't aware I had to list all of them here. There are many features of connected speech that are not in this particular question.

@Lambie Wasn’t implying you shoulda listed them all. It seemed relevant to me that (as everyone here is familiar with) have can be such a strong homophone of of that many native speakers reanalyze it.

@musialmi To add to this answer: sometimes you'll see " o' " written instead of "of" which is pretty much like this, a short and incomplete "of". PS I'd say that this isn't exclusive to nothern England. Just more common there maybe.

All of this is true, but worth saying that Nottingham (home to Nottingham Forest and presumably their supporters) is very much the midlands rather than the North of England.

I wanted to expand on the answer by Araucaria a little.
It's common for many English speakers, not just those speaking British English, to sometimes turn "of" into "uh". This change is the "schwa" that was mentioned in Araucaria's answer. How often this happens varies a lot by region, but most English speakers do it at least occasionally.
For example:

"A lot of the time I just go on ahead."
Will be pronounced more like "A lot uh the time...".

It's also worth noting that this can happen to the article "a". Which means that the example listed above will end up being pronounced like:

"Uh lot uh the time I just go on ahead."


To piggyback on the addition to Araucaria's answer made by fatalerrer, saying "of" as "uh" is common in dialects of American English too.
What is important to notice is that the -uh- sound  sometimes gloms onto the preceding syllable and sometimes onto the following syllable:

For portions uh-that first half we really sort-uh dominated them.

In the first instance, it is a prepositional phrase, "of that first half", and in the second instance, it is the adverbial expression "sort of".
The parsing rhythms isolate the constituent phrase:
uh-that-first-half
really-sort-uh

Hence the words sorta and kinda.

@trlkly You coulda added more examples.  I woulda mentioned "shoulda". :P

@XanderHenderson Apart from those involve the reduction of have, not the reduction of of! ;)

I think you might be referring to Fatalerrer's post, not JamesK's?

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore. You've clearly never seen my students' writing. :D

@XanderHenderson: Re You coulda added more examples - that's wrong! Almost all native Anglophones would articulate /v/ between sorta and a word starting with a vowel such as added. The key point in Tim's answer is that the voiced /s/ at the end of portions gets slurred into a minimal schwa before the next word because it starts with a consonant. In such contexts we routinely throw out the /v/, but not in could've added.

@FumbleFingers   Though I do agree could've is far more frequent, there are some speakers of AmE who do say things like You coulda asked me first before taking my bike.  The word asked (or whatever) gets an extra puff of breath and comes out rather plosive -- reflecting the speaker's irritation.   The hum of the vee of [ vasked] makes the transition to the initial vowel of "asked" much gentler and smoother by comparison.

@TimR: Yes, very occasionally, (in AmE more than BrE, I feel), the /v/ is dropped completely where of is followed by a vowel. But I think there's always a weird little "AmE glottal stop" there instead, in such cases (which I have the impression is more common in AAVE than "standard" AmE, but what do I know?).
